# how can i solve ldconfig create link with version number

Tags: c++, ld

Suppose I have `/a/lib/dir` that has files

```
-rwxrwxr-x libboost_signals.so
-rwxrwxr-x libboost_signals.so.1.55.0
```

And I create a file: `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/testlib.conf` with content

```
/a/lib/dir
```

And run

```
sudo ldconfig
sudo ldconfig -v | head

libboost_signals.so.1.55.0 -> libboost_signals.so.1.55.0
```

Since ldconfig create a link `libboost_signals.so.1.55.0` not `libboost_signals.so`,

I can't use `-lboost_signals` when use g++ to compile the source code.

But `-L/a/lib/dir/ -lboost_signals` is ok.

---

Edit the .bashrc file as:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/a/lib/dir
```

then

```
source .bashrc
```

will be the same result.

So what is the correct way to add system LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't use `-lboost_signals` when use g++ to compile the source code.
>
> But `-L/a/lib/dir/ -lboost_signals` is ok.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` control the behaviour of the run-time linker `ld.so` only and do not affect the linking of the object files and libraries done by `ld`, this is why `-L/a/lib/dir/` must be used.

There is no config file or environment variable to add to `ld` linker path. People normally hard-code extra linker paths in the makefile. Makefiles often consider `LDFLAGS` environment variable though.

Comment: Thank you. I know now. I thought it would also affect the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Once you add directory to ldconfig, or to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it knows all the shared libs in this directory. 
It includes the both shared libs. 
If the lib appears twice in two paths, it will take the later.

ldconfig just menage the name resolving of shared libs. it doesn't create any links. you should create the links.

You find the `-lboost_signals` because you have the `libboost_signals.so`.

`libboost_signals.so` should be soft link to `libboost_signals.so.1.55.0`.
But it look like you copied it. if you replace the `libboost_signals.so.1.55.0` your programs will continue to use the old `libboost_signals.so`

Try this:

```
cd /a/lib/dir
rm libboost_signals.so
link -s libboost_signals.so.1.55.0 libboost_signals.so
```

**EDIT:** run ldconfig like this:

```
sudo ldconfig -p | grep libboost_signals
```

I guess you will see the both files

Comment: I've try this before asking this question. it always show `libboost_signals.so.1.55.0 -> libboost_signals.so.1.55.0`. And `man ldconfig` shows `ldconfig  creates,  updates,  and  removes the necessary links and cache`

Comment: Yes, `-p` do show the `libboost_signals.so`, But still not work. Thank you. I'm sorry for reply until now. I think Maxim Yegorushkin is right.